# sed, convert single backslash to double backslash

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I have a json string, which has a potpourri of doubly escaped/singly escaped newline chars. Json parser doesn't allow its string value to have single backslash escapes.

I need to uniformly make all of them to double escapes

Content looks like,

```
this newline must not be changed ---- \\n
this newline must be changed - \n
```

When i run sed command,

```
 sed -i 's/([^\])\n/\\n/g' ~/Desktop/sedTest
```

it is not replacing anything

`([^\])`, this pattern is used to not change `\n` that already has one more backslash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
sed -i 's,\([^\\]\)\\n,\1\\\\n,'  file
sed -i 's,\([^\]\)\\n,\1\\\\n,'  file
```

where

- `\` must be escaped by `\\\\`
- `\( .. \)` is the capture pattern
- `\1` on right hand is the first captured pattern.
- second form with a single `\` in `[^\]` as per @cuonglm suggestion.

You need to keep the pattern, or it will be discarded.

Comment: in simpler sed replaces like, `sed 's,abc,def,`, i never have to capture a pattern to make sure, that the pattern gets replaced.. in this case alone, why is `\1` used to capture it?

Comment: in s/abc/dev/ , abc is discarded.

Comment: makes sense....

Comment: The second backslash inside the square brackets is unnecessary. If you use `-r` for versions of `sed` that support it (or `-E` on OS X, et al) you can eliminate the backslashes before the parentheses. `sed -ri 's,([^\])\\n,\1\\\\n,'`

Answer (score 3):

Given your sample input:

```
$ cat /tmp/foo
this newline must not be changed ---- \\n
this newline must be changed - \n
```

This seems to do what you want:

```
$ sed -e 's@\([^\]\)\\n@\1\\\\n@' /tmp/foo
this newline must not be changed ---- \\n
this newline must be changed - \\n
```

Comment: hi, why do we need `\1` in the destination pattern?

Comment: Assume the input was:  `foo\n`.  The `[^\]` part capture part will match the second `o` in `foo`.  The `\1` is a group that contains that portion of the match.  I include `\1` so that you don't loose that character.

Answer (score 2):

With `\n` in the LHS, you attempted to match a newline character instead of literal `\n`.

Try:

```
sed -e 's/\([^\]\)\(\\n\)/\1\\\2/g' file
```

or shorter with extended regular expression:

```
sed -E 's/([^\])(\\n)/\1\\\2/g' file
```